# UICollectionView: isDragging property isn't in correct state

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have full-screen UICollectionView cells (first-left -> last-right). When I scroll to the last cell I check 3 properties: isTracking, isDragging and isDecelerating. 
When I am on the last cell drag a little bit to the left (to see pice of the previous cell) and then (without lifting the finger) drag to the right (anchor the cell). End touch and check properties.

After this procedure state of properties:

```
isTracking = NO; //false
isDragging = YES; //true
isDecelerating = NO; // false
```

The problem is, that isDragging state saves for a long time and during this time UICollectingView shows me isDragging in true state (but nobody interact with the cell). I need this property to understand when to reload collection. State refreshes only after new dragging.

So, the question is, how can I improve my code and behavior of the UICollectionView to get the correct value from isDragging property?
Are there any ways to understand that collecitonView in "quiet" state?

P.S. I am using clear native UICollectionView without any custom classes and multithreading

Edited: added question "Are there ... "quiet" state?"

Answer (score 1):

You should not be polling `isTracking` and `isDragging` to learn when a scroll is over. Use the delegate methods `scrollViewDidEndDragging(_:willDecelerate:)` and `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_:)`.

Comment: I am using these methods, but in my case it is not a solution, because delegates call after interacting. App downloads data form the internet and I want to show new data for the user asap. What if user stays on the cell for 1 minute or more, during this time I am trying to reload collectionView but isDragging key shows me that someone interacting with the cells, before reload the CollectionView I want to be sure that it is in "quiet state". Ofc I can add my own bool variable to methods `scrollViewDidEndDragging`, `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` but it is not the solution that I am looking for.

Comment: " App downloads data form the internet and I want to show new data for the user asap." Problem is, you said nothing of this in your question. Basically you've asked the wrong question. Try asking about the actual problem, not some x-y problem.

Comment: Your answer is kind of work-around for real iOS SDK issue. As I mentioned above "I need this property to understand when to reload collection". Are there any ways to understand that collecitonView in "quiet" state?

Comment: If "quiet" means "scrolling has ended", this is not a workaround at all — it's what you do. Delegate methods cover _every_ possibility for learning that scrolling has ended.